# jQuery from html div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to refactor my code to jQuery

this is my existing line I'm trying to change along with the html:

```js
var detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");
```

```html
<div id="detailsPane">
  <img src="images/blank-detail.jpg" width="346" height="153" id="itemDetail" />
  <div id="description"></div>
</div>
```

I was trying this and it wouldn't work:

```
var detailDiv = $("#detailsPane #description");
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the element? You are just selecting it

Comment: What about it "doesn't work"? You  don't need `#detailsPane` but it shouldn't do any harm.

Comment: change #description to class ... you can not use # twice because its ID and this should be unique on one page.

Comment: @daremachine no thats wrong, there are no duplicate IDs

Comment: @daremachine um, what?

Comment: The only thing that might not work is the order. Your javascript has to be executed after DOM is loaded into browser. So eithr wrap indo document.ready or put the script at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the jQuery version, you've got a jQuery object and a DOM element in the other. It appears you're still treating `detailDiv` as a DOM element.

You can access the DOM element in the jQuery version and that will give you an identical result in both cases:

```
var detailDiv = $("#description")[0];
//                               ^^^ this gets the DOM element
```

---

Side note:

As ids should be unique, the `#detailsPane` is not necessary but also isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `document.getElementById("description");` directly translates to `$("#description");`

(*keep in mind that `id` must be unique so the `#detailsPane` is not required.*)

But your code does not really do something, just creating a reference to that element.

---

Now, if you have code below that deals with the `detailDiv` then it would not work as that variable would now hold a jQuery object and not a reference to the DOM element directly. If you want a direct DOM reference then use

```
var detailDiv = $("#description").get(0); // or $("#description")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First nested ID still work with jQuery (though it's not needed you could directly use only $('#description') and it would do the same thing)

Check [code pen example](https://codepen.io/anilnamde/pen/dWzOVR?editors=1111) 
[jQuery method chaining](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/what-is-chaining-in-jquery.html)

```
//Existing expectation is html element
var detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");

// to get html element you have to use .get(). 
// By default jQuery returns wrapped element for chaining
console.log($('#detailsPane #description').get(0));
// same as above
console.log($('#description').get(0));

console.log(detailDiv);
```